# DnnApiController returns 401 for non Super Users

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke

I have a Dotnetnuke module that uses angular.js as its client side and WebApi as its server side :
Here's my Controller :

```
public class AppController:DnnApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<LinkInfo> GetLinks()
        {
            return AppInitializerBase.GetLinks();
        }
}
```

As you can see I have no [SupportedModules] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] and [DnnAuthorize].
So far I was using my module using host (Super User) and everything was working fine.
Now I have defined a registered user and I want to use this user but DNN keeps getting 401.

I have added ModuleId,TabId and RequestVerificationToken to headers of my requests as follows:

```
config.headers = {
                'ModuleId': sf.getModuleId(),
                'TabId': sf.getTabId(),
                'RequestVerificationToken': sf.getAntiForgeryValue()
            };
```

but still I am getting 401.
Any idea why it is not working with non Super Users?

Comment: If you debug the javascript for setting the config.headers, do you have the tabId and moduleId?

Comment: @DotNetNuclear yes both tabId and moduleId are set.I even check headers of my request and all of them are set

Comment: Try adding [AllowAnonymous] to the GetLinks webapi controller method.  That should get rid of the 401.  Once that is tested, add the code for your routes to your question so we can make sure the module folder name on the route matches the one you initialize on the client sf object.  Then you can secure the api using the SupportedModules.